# Transforming a minimization problem to a maximization problem

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning

I have an objective to minimize the transmission delay (D) and energy cost (E) for a wireless network device.

While I am solving it using reinforcement learning (Q-Learning to be exact), hence I have to solve it to find the maximum for the value function. Hence (simplistically) if my Cost is $C(t) = T(t) + D(t)$ and I have to find $\min \gamma ^t C(t)$, is this mathematically equivalent to the following?

$$\max \gamma^t \frac{1}{C(t)}$$

Does it means if I solve for the above expressions, I practically solved the $\min \gamma^tC(t)$ problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cost is strictly positive, then yes, that will work - theoretically. Your optimizer may have numerical problems with any derivatives because of the reciprocal.

It's usually far easier to just maximize the negative: $-\gamma^tC(t)\to\max$.

Comment: On this point, can you please guide me between the difference in using additive versus multiplicative inverse for transforming a maximization problem into a minimization problem (and vice versa)? One that I can see from your answer is the problem with finding derivate.

Comment: Well, the main advantage is that if you have the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}C(t)$, then the derivative of $-C(t)$ is extremely easy to calculate, it's just $-\frac{d}{dt}C(t)$ - simple, fast, easy, numerically *exactly* as stable as the original derivative. The derivative of $\frac{1}{C(t)}$ is more problematic: $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{C(t)}=-\frac{1}{\big(\frac{d}{dt}C(t)\big)^2}$. Zeros in $\frac{d}{dt}C(t)$ turn into *divisions* by zero in the quotient. You really don't want that for numerical reasons.